# How to add datepicker in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add the datepicker in wordpress, but when I click on field it doesn't show the date picker.

Added in footer (without jquery file as I checked in source code jquery-3.5.1.min.js is already included):

jQuery is included as I can see this in source code of the page `<script src='http://localhost/IEP_UAT/wp-content/themes/iep/scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-js'></script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

page-test.php:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />

<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
</script>
<style>
```

I can see this in console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

When I change

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
```

to

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

Then I can see this error in console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Have you included jquery correct? Because It looks like you havent.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks for the reply,
Yes jQuery is included as I can see this in source code of the page `<script src='http://localhost/IEP_UAT/wp-content/themes/iep/scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-js'></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out answer my self.

jQuery script is added in the page file which loads before the jQuery get included.
So I moved script tag code at the bottom of footer page.
Problem fixed.

Comment: When dealing with wordpress and JS scripts. Do not just drop a `<script>`-tag in the footer template. Instead use e.g. the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hooks in the *functions.php*. Loading the script via script tag in your footer might be easier, but you may run into compatability problems with plugins, themes or even your wordpress core.

Answer (score 0):

To use Jquery and daterangepicker you can make sure that the libraries of jquery and daterangepicker are loaded first

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-YdYyWQf8AS4WSB0WWdc3FbQ3Ypdm0QCWD2k4hgfqbQbRCJBEgX0iAegkl2S1Evma5ImaVXLBeUkIlP6hQ1eYKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

JS:

```
<script src='http://localhost/IEP_UAT/wp-content/themes/iep/scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-RCgrAvvoLpP7KVgTkTctrUdv7C6t7Un3p1iaoPr1++3pybCyCsCZZN7QEHMZTcJTmcJ7jzexTO+eFpHk4OCFAg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

After that create javascript code. To use the $ symbol, you can add $ to the function argument like this

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
</script>
```